# Ios6.1 device app crashing

Tags: ios6, crash

I developed an app and it is running fine in iOS 5.1 in iOS device.  But when running the app on iOS 6.1 device app is crashing with the error.

libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary.

But it is working fine with iOS 5.0/ios 6.1 simulators.

Comment: What type of app is it? If possible please provide few more details :)

Comment: while navigating to other controller which contains tableview the app is crashing in the present page.